# require not defined error on bundled JS reactjs

Tags: javascript, django, npm, reactjs

I'm new to Django and ReactJS, was trying to compile a simple JSX code to JS using this tutorial : http://geezhawk.github.io/2016/02/02/using-react-with-django-rest-framework.html 
Didn't work, so I used `npm run dev` to compile, now it worked but giving error in browser console : Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined
Here is my webpack.config.js

```
    var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');


module.exports = {
    //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,
    //the entry point we created earlier. Note that './' means
    //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension  now,
    //because you will specify extensions later in the `resolve` section
    entry: './assets/js/index',

    output: {
        //where you want your compiled bundle to be stored
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        //naming convention webpack should use for your files
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    },
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: {
    react: 'react'
}, // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder

    plugins: [
        //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        //makes jQuery available in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            //React: "react",
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            //a regexp that tells webpack use the following loaders on all
            //.js and .jsx files
            {test: /\.jsx?$/,
                //we definitely don't want babel to transpile all the files in
                //node_modules. That would take a long time.
                /*exclude: /node_modules/,*/
                //use the babel loader
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    //specify that we will be dealing with React code
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        //tells webpack where to look for modules
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
     }
    }
```

And assets/bundles/index.js

```
    var React = require('react')
    var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
    //snaha//
    var BooksList = React.createClass({
    loadBooksFromServer: function(){
        console.log(123454657);
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this)
        })
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadBooksFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadBooksFromServer,
                    this.props.pollInterval)
    },
    render: function() {
        if (this.state.data) {
            console.log('DATA!')
            var bookNodes = this.state.data.map(function(book){
                return <li> {book.title} </li>
            })
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello React!</h1>
                <ul>
                    {bookNodes}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
      }
   })

     ReactDOM.render(<BooksList url='/api/' pollInterval={1000} />,
    document.getElementById('container'))
```

And templates/body.html

```
    {% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Hello React
        {% block content %}
            {{ id }}
        {% endblock %}
     </title>
      </head>
      <body>
     <div id="container"></div>
      {% render_bundle 'main' %}
      </body>
      </html>
```

Anything I'm missing? [here is my Django project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2E2u.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've solved it!
Problem was : it was trying to get variable react where as React.js on browser was providing variable React!
So I simple change of externals of webpack.config.js to

```
    externals: {
    React: 'react'
},
```

solved the issue!

Next Problem Faced :

"process was not defined"

Solution : added

```
var env = process.env.WEBPACK_ENV;
```

to top of webpack.config.js 
and

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
}),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
  }
})
```

into the plugins part of model.export

So Final webpack.config.js would be :

```
    var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var env = process.env.WEBPACK_ENV;


module.exports = {
    //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,
    //the entry point we created earlier. Note that './' means
    //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension  now,
    //because you will specify extensions later in the `resolve` section
    entry: './assets/js/index',

    output: {
        //where you want your compiled bundle to be stored
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        //naming convention webpack should use for your files
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    },
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: {
    React: 'react'
}, // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder

    plugins: [
        //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        //makes jQuery available in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            //React: "react",
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
         new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
         new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
      }
    })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            //a regexp that tells webpack use the following loaders on all
            //.js and .jsx files
            {test: /\.jsx?$/,
                //we definitely don't want babel to transpile all the files in
                //node_modules. That would take a long time.
                /*exclude: /node_modules/,*/
                //use the babel loader
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    //specify that we will be dealing with React code
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        //tells webpack where to look for modules
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

Now Enjoy React! Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Holy moly this was a painful experience...reversing the order of the `externals` properties fixed my *module not defined* problem as well when loading libraries separately via `<script>`

Answer (score 1):

Can you look if you have all the requirements installed.

Look inside package.json. You should have react noted in requirements if you do run.

```
npm install
```

If you don't, then run

```
npm install react --save
```

ps: in my option if you are running Webpack try to add babel to Webpack presets and write javascript in ES2015 specification.

Comment: yes npm was there, so is react. Can you please give me a clear documentation of weback, babel , es2015 etc? Currently I'm not clean with all of these.